# Cordova/phonegap - 3.4 iOS Calendar plugin thread warning unable to fix

Tags: ios, multithreading, cordova, phonegap-plugins, cordova-plugins

Can't seem to figure out where to fix this warning.  I'm fairly new to this and I don't know objective-c very well.

I am using a calendar plugin from https://github.com/EddyVerbruggen/Calendar-PhoneGap-Plugin

When I add the event to the calendar and press 'OK' then the app breaks with"

```
THREAD WARNING: ['Calendar'] took '1869.833984' ms. Plugin should use a background thread.
```

I've seen code on the cordova documentation for threading but unsure where to add the code and how to use it.

```
- (void)myPluginMethod:(CDVInvokedUrlCommand*)command
{
// Check command.arguments here.
[self.commandDelegate runInBackground:^{
    NSString* payload = nil;
    // Some blocking logic...
    CDVPluginResult* pluginResult = [CDVPluginResult resultWithStatus:CDVCommandStatus_OK messageAsString:payload];
    // The sendPluginResult method is thread-safe.
    [self.commandDelegate sendPluginResult:pluginResult callbackId:command.callbackId];
}];
}
```

I really appreciate any help, thanks.

Comment: You should maybe add an issue to the plugin's github repo? I doubt it is your fault and is instead a bug w/ the plugin.

Comment: Thanks for reply, I've tried this hoping to hear back with something.

Comment: have u found any way to use this?